# OpenSSL Blinding implementation

Tags: openssl, rsa

Basically I'm trying to compare OpenSSL with other libraries, regarding timing attacks. I am working on RSA signatures. So OpenSSL and the other library implemented a blinding technique to prevent these timing attacks (to hide the exact time that the signature took to be performed).
I found out that OpenSSL is performing better than the others. But I couldn't manage to find the implementation technique/code that OpenSSL used.

I know the textbook blinding technique and I found the exact implementation code for the other library (PyCryptodome) But I couldn't find it for OpenSSL. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think if you just search for the word "blinding" in the source tree you'll find it.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk by "source tree" do you mean the github repository ? 
I mean I can spend my time trying to understand what they did. but don't they have some sort of a documentation or book etc,  that explane what they did. and at the end of the day I need a "reference" and I don't want to just point out some code lines. In PyCryptodome they at least added some comments near the code explaining exactly how they did it.